# looking for a book for general audience

Tags: reference-request

While browsing through amazon a while ago, I came across a book intended to explain aspects of US laws to the general audience.  One particular example shown the sample pages is about a person who killed a bird that turned out to be on the endanged specices act, and was later found guity even though this person claimed to be not aware of this particular detail of the law.

I'd be most appreciative if anyone can help me track down this book.  Thanks!

Disclaimer:  I am interested in this book, and not about this particular case, and I am certainly arguing for/against this judgment.